# Video playout software and hardware requirements for simple TV channel

Tags: broadcasting, broadcast

What would minimum hardware requirements be on Win10 desktop/server for streaming  SD channel ? Which is the simplest playout solution you can recommend ?

I have offers from 2.000,00 € for hardware and software up to 35.000,00 €, all basicly doing same thing. There are some new "cloud" services that offer it all but for enormous 80.000,00 € per year.

My requirements are very simple. Ingest - schedule - play. Graphics: only logo. And Desktop/server to handle it all.

I understand that big TV channels need load of things, graphics, multiple channels, safety etc. But what about those simple channels ? Any solutions out of the box for reasonable price ?

Comment: You gave a lot of anti-requirements but not much of actual requirements. What is a reasonable price? What is your skill level? What is your time investment? What kind of reliability are you looking for? What is your distribution (factors in to quality and other equipment you might need)? How much storage do you need (in hours)?

Comment: As Michael asked, you need to give more detail as to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Cheapest solution: OBS for broadcasting, mplayer for video playback, someone who will programm simple schedule for $100. If you don't need exact schedule programming, you can just make playlists playback for free! Here no instruction how to setup it for your needs, but if you is advanced user, you can do everything youself.

If you need advert breaks, logo overlays and so on, it can be programmed with infrastructure of OBS, but you can reach limits very fast. You can try to hire freelancers who will maintain your infrastructure and wishes.

Main price for "out of box" solutions comes from any guarantees what will be provided to you. Cheap infrastructure guarantees nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to vMix , a software that take advantage of NDI.

Or you use MPlayer/VLC as playout on another machine and use OBS + NDI to capture back the playout and broadcast

Comment: How does NDI address the minimal requirements the user gave? All NDI is replace SDI wiring with a network.